# Equally divide paths in svg speedometer

Tags: javascript, svg

How do I distribute 10 paths equally around the circle in the following svg so that I can show value upto 50 with each path being equal to 5 units.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9dfgvhkj/

The code:

```
<svg id="gaugeSpeedSvg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="width: 350px; height: 350px; background:white; border-radius: 50%; 
                                    box-shadow: rgba(21, 55, 172, 0.25) 0px 0px 32px, rgb(10, 220, 30) 0px -192px 192px -240px inset, rgb(10, 220, 30) 0px 0px 2px -1px inset;" xml:space="preserve">
                                    <path style="fill: rgb(227, 18, 18); display: block;" d="M12.9,75.5c0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9,1,1.4l7.6-5.7c-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.7-0.8-1.1L12.9,75.5z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(241, 45, 96); display: block;" d="M6.7,62.4C6.9,62.9,7,63.5,7.2,64l9.1-3c-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2L6.7,62.4z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(255, 75, 168); display: block;" d="M5,47.9c0,0.6,0,1.1,0,1.7l9.5,0.1c0-0.5,0-0.9,0-1.4L5,47.9z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(247, 50, 191); display: block;" d="M8,33.7c-0.2,0.5-0.4,1.1-0.6,1.6l9,3.1c0.1-0.4,0.3-0.9,0.5-1.3L8,33.7z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(238, 26, 220); display: block;" d="M15.5,21.2c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.9-1.1,1.3l7.5,5.8c0.3-0.4,0.6-0.7,0.9-1.1L15.5,21.2z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(102, 24, 205); display: block;" d="M26.4,11.7c-0.5,0.3-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.9l5.3,7.9c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.5,1-0.7L26.4,11.7z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(21, 55, 172); display: block;" d="M39.9,6.1c-0.5,0.1-1.1,0.3-1.6,0.4l2.5,9.2c0.4-0.1,0.8-0.2,1.2-0.3L39.9,6.1z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(44, 144, 213); display: block;" d="M54.5,5.2c-0.6,0-1.1-0.1-1.7-0.1l-0.6,9.5c0.4,0,0.9,0.1,1.3,0.1L54.5,5.2z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(75, 247, 255); display: block;" d="M68.6,9C68,8.7,67.5,8.5,67,8.3l-3.6,8.8c0.4,0.2,0.8,0.3,1.2,0.5L68.6,9z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(40, 237, 153); display: block;" d="M80.6,17c-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.7-1.3-1.1l-6.2,7.2c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.6,1,0.9L80.6,17z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(10, 220, 30); display: block;" d="M89.6,28.6c-0.2-0.5-0.5-1-0.8-1.5L80.6,32c0.2,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.6,1.1L89.6,28.6z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(10, 220, 30); display: block;" d="M94.4,42.2c-0.1-0.5-0.2-1.1-0.3-1.6l-9.4,2c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.9,0.2,1.3L94.4,42.2z"></path>

                                    <path style="fill: rgb(10, 220, 30); display: block;" d="M94.5,56.8c0.1-0.5,0.1-1.1,0.2-1.7l-9.4-1c-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.9-0.2,1.3L94.5,56.8z"></path>


                                    <path style="fill: rgb(10, 220, 30); display: block;" d="M89.9,80.1c0.5-0.7,1-1.3,1.4-1.9l-12-8.2c-0.3,0.4-0.6,0.9-0.9,1.3L89.9,80.1z"></path>
                                </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me point out, as an FYI, that `display: block` is basically meaningless in SVG. That is an HTML concept.

Anyway, to your problem.  The simplest way is to define one tick/mark of your speedo, then use rotation transforms to distribute them at regular intervals.

Your speedo range seems to cover a bit less than 3/4 of the circumference of your circle (270 degrees).  So let's go for for a range of 250 degrees to make things simple.

So lets start by defining the initial tick mark that we are going to re-use.  For simplicity, we'll define the middle one that is straight up and down vertically.

```css
svg {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background:white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(21, 55, 172, 0.25) 0px 0px 32px, rgb(10, 220, 30) 0px -192px 192px -240px inset, rgb(10, 220, 30) 0px 0px 2px -1px inset;
}
```

```html
<svg id="gaugeSpeedSvg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

   <path id="initial" d="M 49,5 L 51,5 L 50.65,14.5, L 49.35,14.5 Z"></path>

</svg>
```

Next we can use the `<use>` element to make copies of that tick shape with varying amounts of rotation applied.  The rotation transform will be variants of:

```
transform="rotate(25, 50,50)`
```

The 25 means 25 degrees rotation. That's because we want to divide the 250 degrees speedo range into 10 divisions.  The 50,50 part is the centre of rotation we want to use. (50,50) is the centre of the `viewBox` - which is the centre of the SVG.

```css
svg {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background:white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(21, 55, 172, 0.25) 0px 0px 32px, rgb(10, 220, 30) 0px -192px 192px -240px inset, rgb(10, 220, 30) 0px 0px 2px -1px inset;
}
```

```html
<svg id="gaugeSpeedSvg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-125, 50,50)"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-100, 50,50)"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-75, 50,50)"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-50, 50,50)"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-25, 50,50)"/>

   <path id="initial" d="M 49,5 L 51,5 L 50.65,14.5, L 49.35,14.5 Z"></path>

   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(25, 50,50)"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(50, 50,50)"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(75, 50,50)"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(100, 50,50)"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(125, 50,50)"/>

</svg>
```

The final step is to add the colours you want.  Assuming you want the same ones as in your original SVG.

Note that in this version, we have to separate out the "initial" tick as a definition. Then use that definition for all 11 displayed ticks. That is because if we gave that one a colour, then we wouldn't be able to give the copies individual colours. The colour on the initial one would have over-ridden any other colour we specified on the `<use>` elements.

```css
svg {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background:white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: rgba(21, 55, 172, 0.25) 0px 0px 32px, rgb(10, 220, 30) 0px -192px 192px -240px inset, rgb(10, 220, 30) 0px 0px 2px -1px inset;
}
```

```html
<svg id="gaugeSpeedSvg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
   <defs>
      <path id="initial" d="M 49,5 L 51,5 L 50.65,14.5, L 49.35,14.5 Z"/>
   </defs>

   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-125, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(227, 18, 18);"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-100, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(241, 45, 96);"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-75, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(255, 75, 168);"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-50, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(247, 50, 191);"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(-25, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(238, 26, 220);"/>

   <use xlink:href="#initial" style="fill: rgb(102, 24, 205);"/>

   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(25, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(21, 55, 172);"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(50, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(44, 144, 213);"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(75, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(75, 247, 255);"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(100, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(40, 237, 153);"/>
   <use xlink:href="#initial" transform="rotate(125, 50,50)" style="fill: rgb(10, 220, 30);"/>

</svg>
```